About creating a Virtual Environment in Anaconda Prompt
When I run this command:
(base) C:\Users\Sam>python -m venv cuda

It gives error as :
Error: Command '['C:\\Users\\Sam\\cuda\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-m', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

I installed the cuda but it not working.
